# Как сохранить форму jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, form

Имеется динамически образуемая форма:

```
<span span_id="2" class="span_new">
<form id="f_news"><h1><input type="text" name="rtitle" value="Заголовок"></h1>
<textarea name="rtext">Текст</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="rid" value="2">
<a id="btn_save" href="">Сохранить</a>
<a id="btn_cancel" href="">Отмена</a>
<a id="btn_attach" href="">Прикрепить</a>
</form>
</span>
```

Она обрабатывается следующим образом jQuery:

```
 $(function(){
    $('.span_new').on('click', '#btn_save', function( event ){
       alert('save');
        event.preventDefault();
        var posting = $.post('/admin/assets/news/news_ajax.php','act=update&'+$('#f_news').serialize());
            posting.done(function( data ) {
            if(data){
                       alert('done');
                    }
});

    });         
});
```

и соответственно скрипт news_ajax.php:

```
<?php
if(!defined('rPATH')) define('rPATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$act = array('add', 'update','del');
$res=array('res'=>'ошибка');
if( !array_key_exists('act',$_POST) or !in_array($_POST['act'],$act)) { echo   json_encode($res);exit;}

include rPATH.'/libs/safemysql.class.php';

$opts = array('db' => 'mysite');
$db = new SafeMySQL($opts);
$id_us = str_replace('span_','',$_POST['rid']);

function update(){ 
global $db;
$res=array('res'=>'ошибка в аргументах запроса');
$id_us = str_replace('span_','',$_POST['rid']);
unset($_POST['rid']);
unset($_POST['act']);
if(empty($id_us)){ echo json_encode($res);exit;}

$sql  = "UPDATE `mdb_news` SET title=?s,text=?s WHERE id=?i";
$db->query($sql,$_POST['rtitle'],$_POST['rtext'], $id_us);

}
```

Не могу добиться обновления данных в базе при сохранении. Где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: В консоли показывается, что данные отсылаются? На сервере в посте вы смотрели - точно что-то приходит? А коннект точно есть? А что в драйвере бд написано? С плейсхолдерами там так работает драйвер (с доп буквенными обозначениями)?  А какие вообще ошибки выдает? .... вот сколько я вопросов накопал, которые вы как минимум себе должны задать и посмотреть это)) ну и здесь написать

Comment: Спасибо, решилась проблема добавлением перед функцией в news_ajax.php строчки echo $_POST['act'](); Правда смысл мне ее не  ясен

Comment: Ну предположу, что так как в `$_POST['act']` лежит значение `update`, переданное в пост запросе, то в результате подстановки значения получается `update();` что в свою очередь по логике вещей запустит на исполнение функцию `function update()`....... и предположу, что убрав `echo` все равно будет все продолжать работать.

Comment: Все верно, убрал echo и работает. Спасибо)